# Attributed text not appearing in simulator even though it is in IB

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, interface-builder

I am building an FAQ view for our app. I would like to have a single textView containing all of the questions and answers. I have built that up and added a few lines of text for testing. I'd like the questions to be bold and the responses to be normal weight. In IB I was able to do that using attributed text. It even looks correct in IB but when I run the app in the simulator or on device it changes to a system default font.

Screen shot link - https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tDov.png

This is the debug output --

```
(lldb) po self.faqTextView.attributedText
Test 1:{
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7f91b94bdee0> font-family:     \".HelveticaNeueInterface-Regular\"; font-weight: normal; font-style:     normal; font-size: 14.00pt";
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0,   ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n    140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n    308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
}
```

I also noticed that if I print out all the fonts in the app the one I am trying to use is not listed the same as the others --

```
2015-09-03 09:23:30.633 [19665:3068968] Font family name = Open Sans
2015-09-03 09:23:30.633 [19665:3068968] Font names = (
    "OpenSans-ExtraboldItalic",
    "OpenSans-SemiboldItalic",
    "OpenSans-Extrabold",
    "OpenSans-BoldItalic",
    "OpenSans-Italic",
    "OpenSans-Semibold",
    "OpenSans-Light",
    OpenSans,
    "OpenSansLight-Italic",
    "OpenSans-Bold"
)
```

I have tried re-adding the font, as well as re-naming the font and adding a second instance of it to the project. That one did not work either.

I followed the instructions on [codewithchris](http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/) (multiple times) to make sure that I added the fonts in correctly but still unable to get this to work.

If I change the font to a built-in font like helvetica neue bold and regular everything appears correctly in IB and the simulator.

I know there is an open radar for a similar bug but from what I have been able to find it was fixed in the Xcode 7 betas but from my testing I am still having the same issue. Also because of the strange output in the font list I think it may have to do with the font itself.

Comment: I've had the same problem while using custom fonts. I do believe this is a bug with ios, so my solution was to use a font that comes with IOS which closely resembles your custom font.

Comment: If I set the attributes via code it seems to be working. Adds a ton of work but might have to be the way to go for this.

Comment: hmm I never thought about adding in via code. I'll try it next time.